# Blob ID matching over multiple frames in C++ (image analysis)

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, analysis, matching

I'm working on a blob matching and tracking library in C++. Currently I'm using **OpenCV** to detect blobs and try to match blobs in a new frame by checking the position, velocity and size of the blob. This works quite okay and I'm receiving a high blob match rate (95% or higher).

Sometimes blobs fall out of the image or new blobs appear. Now I need to give matched blobs the same ID as they had before. I'm wondering if there are typical or commonly used techniques for doing this. Or even some keywords I can use to Google on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction

I assume you have your blobs in a binary image, simply floodfill each blob with a different color/id, and register overlapping blobs between frames with the same id.

Comment: Hi Viktor, thanks for your reply. Though this will not work with fast moving objects as they will not have overlapping pixels (for example tennis balls).

Answer (score 0):

CCV is used for multiple finger tracking for multi-touch environments. Check out their [tracking code](http://nuicode.com/projects/tbeta/repository/entry/trunk/tbeta/Windows/addons/ofxNCore/src/Tracking/Tracking.cpp). It uses a function `trackKnn` which uses k nearest neighbour algorithm.

You can also use `Kalman Filter` if blobs collide each other. Check out [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713379/question-on-tracking-a-moving-ball-using-kalman-filter)